# Css fixed div area

Tags: css

Hello everyone I have  fixed div area. I put these fixed divs in a one div which I call "page" here is css:

```
.page {
    width: 964px;
    margin-top:6px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image:url(../images2/images/orta_alan_bg_GOLGE.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

But when I check my design with different resolution fixed div area go far from my "page" div

and here is fixed div css:

```
#rocket_left
{
  width:127px;
  height:148px;
  background-image:url(../../images2/images/tapinak_resim.jpg);
  top:244px;
  left: 5.4%;
  position:fixed;
}

#rocket_left_desc
{
 background-image:url(../../images2/images/bg_sol_bslk_tpnk.png); 
  width:130px;
  height:335px;
  top:385px;
  left:70px;
  position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"But when I check my design with different resolution fixed div area go far from my "page" div"` .

this is because when you set an element's position as fixed, its position is calculated relative to the screen, in your case, the elements would always be positioned at:`top:244px; left: 5.4%;` and `top:385px; left:70px;` from the screen.

My suggestion would be to position them absolutely (using `position:absolute;`) and then detect (using JavaScript) if the width of the viewer's screen is greater than your document's width (in your case, that would be 964px), and if it is, then change the position of rockets to `position:fixed;`

here is jQuery code for my suggestion above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($(window).width()>=964){
            $('#rocket_left').css('position','fixed');
            $('#rocket_left').css('position','fixed');
        }
    });
</script>
```

and here is the css you should use (as posted by MarvinLabs):

```
.page {
    position: relative; /* Position context for the rockets */
    width: 964px;
    margin-top:6px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image:url(../images2/images/orta_alan_bg_GOLGE.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

#rocket_left
{
  width:127px;
  height:148px;
  background-image:url(../../images2/images/tapinak_resim.jpg);
  top:244px;
  left: 5.4%;
  position: absolute; /* Absolute positionning within the page */
}

#rocket_left_desc
{
 background-image:url(../../images2/images/bg_sol_bslk_tpnk.png); 
  width:130px;
  height:335px;
  top:385px;
  left:70px;
  position: absolute; /* Absolute positionning within the page */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean to do is to have the rockets positionned relative to the page and not to the browser document. In that case, simply change the positionning instructions:

```
.page {
    position: relative; /* Position context for the rockets */
    width: 964px;
    margin-top:6px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image:url(../images2/images/orta_alan_bg_GOLGE.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

#rocket_left
{
  width:127px;
  height:148px;
  background-image:url(../../images2/images/tapinak_resim.jpg);
  top:244px;
  left: 5.4%;
  position: absolute; /* Absolute positionning within the page */
}

#rocket_left_desc
{
 background-image:url(../../images2/images/bg_sol_bslk_tpnk.png); 
  width:130px;
  height:335px;
  top:385px;
  left:70px;
  position: absolute; /* Absolute positionning within the page */
}
```

Comment: But when I scroll down the div area not scroll down because of position absolute

Comment: You should post a sample page to show your problem. Use http://jsfiddle.com to do that.