# Position fixed div go far when zoom out

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello everyone I want to display div area when I scroll down, the div area must scroll down. So I have used position:fixed and I have fixed div area in a one div which I call "page" div.Here is CSS

```
.page {
    width: 964px;
    margin-top:6px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image:url(../images2/images/orta_alan_bg_GOLGE.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

When I zoom out my fixed div go far from my main div area "page" so how can I solve that issue ?

Here is fixed div

```
#rocket_left
{
  width:127px;
  height:148px;
  background-image:url(../../images2/images/tapinak_resim.jpg);
  top:244px;
  left: 5.4%;
  position:fixed;
}

#rocket_left_desc
{
 background-image:url(../../images2/images/bg_sol_bslk_tpnk.png); 
  width:130px;
  height:335px;
  top:385px;
  left:70px;
  position
}
```

Comment: can you set some fiddle?

Comment: check your code and write again

Comment: maybe bc you have no position at `#rocket_left_desc`...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h3Q6k/ is this what u want?

Comment: this is what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/scv6a/ you have css mistakes

Comment: I'm lookink your fiddle @ŁukaszBorawski

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135186/css-fixed-div-area

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fixed"></div>   
</div>​
```

and css:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 1200px;
}

.fixed {
    width:300px;
    height:30px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000;
    top: 0;
}​
```

and fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/scv6a/

Comment: could you look I have  test site http://88.255.176.42/ you can see rocket_left div area which has temple picture I have used position relative but when zoom out same problem

Comment: in that case you will be always have this effect, this is fixed position (http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning), try with jquery - and think about situation when the screen will have less than 1200px width ...